# Opening a data file from UCL which is not in comma delimited or tab delimited using Python PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I am practising some statistical analysis taking a dataset from UCL repository. Unfortunately, I am unable to identify the format and file type of the dataset file. If someone can help me figure out how to read the file using python pandas, it would be great.

I have tried the `pd.read_csv()` command which works for a normal comma delimited DATA file but got an OS ERROR 22 for this file.

Here is the link to the dataset:

**Link**: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/trains/

**File name**: trains-original.data

Comment: `pd.read_csv('trains-transformed.data', sep='\s+', header=None)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the transformed data. This works:

```
pd.read_csv("trains-transformed.data",header=None,delim_whitespace=True)

   0   1   2      3           4   5           6   7      8   ... 24  25 26 27 28 29 30 31    32
0   5   4   2   long    openrect   3  rectanglod   2  short  ...  0   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  east
1   4   3   2  short     ushaped   1   trianglod   2  short  ...  0   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  east
2   4   2   2  short    openrect   1   circlelod   2  short  ...  0   0  1  0  1  0  0  0  east
3   5   2   2  short    opentrap   1   trianglod   2  short  ...  0   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  east
4   4   3   2  short  dblopnrect   1   trianglod   3   long  ...  0   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  east
5   3   2   2   long  closedrect   3   circlelod   2  short  ...  0   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  west
6   4   2   2  short  dblopnrect   1   circlelod   2  short  ...  0   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  west
7   3   2   3   long  closedrect   1  rectanglod   2  short  ...  0   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  west
8   5   2   2  short    opentrap   1   circlelod   2   long  ...  0   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  west
9   3   1   2  short     ushaped   1  rectanglod   2   long  ...  0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  west
```